# Количество строк в базе SQL

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlite3

Здравствуйте!
Код создает базу данных из более чем 100 строк в SQLite, но открываются только первые сто, при том, что вручную создать новые записи в созданной базе можно. Наверное, стоит какое-то ограничение, но я его в упор не вижу. Помогите, пожалуйста!

```
import urllib.request as ur
from twurl import augment
import json
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('status_new2.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.executescript('''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Status;

CREATE TABLE Status (
    title  TEXT UNIQUE
)''')

print ("* Calling Twitter...")
url = augment('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json', 
 {'screen_name': 'screenname', 'count': '200'} )
connection = ur.urlopen(url)
data = connection.read().decode("utf-8")
info = json.loads(data)
for status in info:
 s = status["text"]

 cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Status (title) 
        VALUES ( ? )''', ( s, ) )

 conn.commit()

print("Done")
```

Comment: Что значит "открываются"? Данные, допустим, вы поместили, а где код для их получения?

Comment: После запуска кода создается база данных, наполненная более чем 100 строками, но когда я открываю полученную базу (просто в sqlite browser), там отображаются только первые 100 строк

Comment: Так может это вопрос, относящийся к программе для просмотра содержимого? Выполните простой SELECT COUNT(*), чтобы узнать сколько строк действительно. Также вопрос может относиться к Twitter API, потому что он может отдавать результаты постранично, а вы могли это не учитывать. Или может вообще максимум сотню отдать, независимо от вашего желания.

Comment: страниц в sqlite browser при этом одна или можно на следующую перейти? https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/master/images/sqlitebrowser.png

Comment: Сохраняйте не все элементы, а, например, пачками по 50. Может у вас sqlite собран с ограничением 100 элементов на вставку (по умолчанию вроде 999). Давайте версию системы, как получаете количество элементов. Больше подробностей, что нам гадать на кофейной гуще то?